# What is preventing the computer from outputting a solution to my program?

Tags: python, debugging

I was writing in python and decided to write a code that would find square numbers and triangle numbers and output the ones that are the same, but when I run my code there is no output.

the source code:

```
import math

s = 2
t = 1

while((s**2) != (t*(t+1)/2)):
 s = s + 1
 t = t + 1 


print (str(s) + " " + str(t))
```

Comment: That loop will not terminate. As with s == t+1 the formula ((t+1)**2) == (t*(t+1)/2) has only two solutions t = -1, t = -2.

Comment: Welcome! Here's some complimentary debugging help https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: What "solutions" do you think your loop is looking for? What's the logic behind the `(s**2) != (t*(t+1)/2)` condition? What the relationship be `s` and `t`?

Comment: the code is meant to run a series of "triangle number" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) and a series of square numbers, and compare them to output which numbers are both triangular and square, therefore the loop should output 36 as that is the smallest number that fits that criteria

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, 2**2 is greater than 1*(1+1)/2)
In the while loop, both s and t are increased by 1, making the difference between the two even greater.
So the while loop is infinite, there is no way for it to stop. The print statement is therefore never executed.